# `KFAS`: how to fit time-varying variance in `regSSM` function

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, variance, kalman-filter

Please, consider the following example from `KFAS` package:

```
install.packages('KFAS')
require(KFAS)

# Drivers

model <- structSSM(y = log(Seatbelts[,"drivers"]), trend = "level", seasonal = "time",
                   X = cbind(log(Seatbelts[,"kms"]), log(Seatbelts[,"PetrolPrice"]), 
                             Seatbelts[,c("law")]))
fit <- fitSSM(inits = rep(-1,3), model = model)
out <- KFS(fit$model, smoothing = "state")      
str(out)
```

You can see `out$model$H` is a single value, that is this model is **not** time-varying in variance of disturbance terms.

See all the arguments of `regSSM` typing:

```
?regSSM
```

`regSSM` help says I can make `H` argument to be time-varying:

> ...
>
> ***H*** is a *p* * *p* covariance matrix (or ***p* * *p* * *n* array in of time-varying case**) of the disturbance terms *epsilon*[ *t* ]
>   of the observation equation. Default gives *p* * *p* zero matrix.
>
> ...

Could you show me how may I fit a time-varying covariance state-space model using `regSSM` and `fitSSM` functions?

The best to me would be if you could use the same example from above.